# How to keep button functionality when adding other views on top of said button in a subclass?

Tags: swift

I have a button in my app, but I have create a UIButton subclass that adds another view and a few labels on top of it. The problem is that now in my app the button does not respond to taps. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: You could add a `tapGesture` to your subclassed `UIButton` and handle the actions accordingly. (Using a protocol would be the best option)

Comment: The problem with that is that Id like to connect multiple buttons to the sane function, you can not do that with gesture recognizers kye

Comment: Why not use an `IBAction` then? You're subclassed button should still support that. Could you show some code? It will make your question a lot easier to understand.

Comment: So in my subclass it basically added a UIView view on top of the button and that UIView took the taps instead of the button, there for the IBAction did not work. I was able to fix this however by setting userInteractionEnabled to false, that makes it so touches go through to the view behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by setting the view that was covering my button with the property

```
userInteractionEnabled = true
```

That allowed for the text to go through my view back to my button